# How to read the tcp option with golang on tcp layer?

Tags: go, tcp

I try to get tcp option from tcp connection on server with golang. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#GetsockoptInt may be useful

Comment: @rogerdpack thank you, Is there any example for how to use this function?

Comment: `TCPConn.File()`,`File.Fd()` and `syscall.GetsockoptInt`

Comment: Note that calling File() on a TCP connection will also switch it to blocking mode, such that reading from or writing to the socket will monopolise an OS thread from that point on.  Keep that in mind if your program will be dealing with a lot of concurrent connections.

Comment: How to call this func? `syscall.GetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.IP_RECVRETOPTS)` report err: `protocol not available`

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Is there any way to avoid this problem?